# Angular 12 ngif condition not executed

Tags: angular

Call Dialog box

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(InfoDialogComponent, {
                maxWidth: "400px",
                data: {
                  type:"Error",
                  title: "Oops. Something went wrong... ",
                  message: response[0].message
                }
              });
```

InfoDialogComponent.ts file

```
export class InfoDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<InfoDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}
```

Html page

```
<h1 *ngif="data?.type === 'Error'" mat-dialog-title style="color: red;">{{data?.title}}</h1>
```

If condition not working

Answer (score 5):

Maybe typo? You need to write `*ngIf` instead of `*ngif`.

Comment: how to accept answer to close. i am new in stackoverflow and please give me 1 mark. my point going down